# How to display duplicate value in a specific field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql query that i'd like to display only those records where a specific field has double entries.

Here is an example of my current output:

```
Test 1        Test2         Test3
1               12            654
2               12            4655
3               15            65987
4               16            3548
5               14            7348
6               14            365
7               17            987
8               L13           6547
9               L13           98687
```

I'd like to pull only the following (only those where Test2 has a count of > 1 and is numeric):

```
Test 1        Test2         Test3
1               12            654
2               12            4655
5               14            7348
6               14            365
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT        *
FROM            Test
WHERE        (Test4 BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (isnumeric(test2) = 1)
Group by Test1
having Count(Distinct(test2)) > 1
ORDER BY Test2, test3
```

Comment: Does your current query not produce the desired output? It is tough to see what is going on here entirely. Can you put together a sqlfiddle? Also, be careful with ISNUMERIC it will return a lot of false positives. By no means am I saying not to use it, but to make sure you understand it pretty poor at filtering only numbers. Things like 1e3 or even $ will return a 1 from ISNUMERIC. You can read more about this topic here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC%28%29/71512/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery for count and selection:

```
Select * From test
where test2 in (
    Select test2 From (
        Select test2, count(*) C from test
        where (Test4 BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (isnumeric(test2) = 1)
        group by test2 
        having count(*) > 1 ) f
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Test2)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(Test2) = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE N > 1;
```